# How can I add a customised layout to my view by using java code?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to develop a finance manager app for Android. I am currently using Android Studio 3.0 Beta 5 and I'm using Java.

I want to create a list on my MainActivity so that when a new transaction is provided, the details of that transaction display in the MainActivity under the older transactions, just like a list.

A listview does not seem a good idea, as I can't insert a simple layout that shows the category, the amount of the transactions, etc as an element of the list (or can I?). Thus, I'm trying to have a new layout appearing when I return from the TransactionActivity to the MainActivity.

Here's some relevant code from the onCreate method in my MainActivity:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // ...

    XmlPullParser parser = getResources().getXml(R.xml.transaction);
    AttributeSet attributes = Xml.asAttributeSet(parser);

    Transaction transaction = (Transaction) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("Transaction"); // imports the transaction object from TransactionActivity
    if (transaction != null) {

        LinearLayout linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.layout_main);
        LinearLayout transactionLayout = new LinearLayout(this, attributes);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        linearLayout.addView(transactionLayout, layoutParams);
    }


}
```

This is R.xml.transaction:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="SKrt"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I've added a simple textView to check if it displays correctly after a transaction is created, but nothing appears on the screen.

Is there a better way to implement all this? If not, how can I make this layout appear on click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to add a customized Layout, you need to create one.

1. In your case since you want a list of transactions, you will need a List View for the activity_main.xml.
2. In order to populate this list, you will need a custom array adapter. You can search the online documentation.  This link might help https://www.caveofprogramming.com/guest-posts/custom-listview-with-imageview-and-textview-in-android.html
3. Since you want a custom view, you will need to create one as in android, you are provided with default views made by the android team. You only need to create a view for a single list item.
4. Afterwards in the implementation of the custom adapter (which you'll be making after making a custom view), you will need to set the layout inflator to used your custom layout instead of the default.

Answer (score 0):

First you should move the **transaction.xml** file from the xml folder to the **layout** folder. Then you should inflate the layout xml

```
View transactionLayout = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.transaction, null);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
linearLayout.addView(transactionLayout, layoutParams);
```

You should be able to see the TextView after this.

You can also use a ListView but then you will need to create a ListAdapter and inflate the **transactionLayout** in the getView() method of the adapter.